# How to correctly install/update a .deb 3rd party driver on Ubuntu 16.04.2 TLS Server (mpt3sas v15)?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, server, lts

I'm trying to update the `mpt3sas` driver on a clean Ubuntu 16.04.2 TLS Server, kernel 4.4.0-66-generic (amd64). The driver is used to handle a LSI card (SAS300-8i). The installed version is `12.100.00.00` and I would like to update to `15.00.00.00-1`. I downloaded the official LSI `mpt3sas` driver and followed the instructions. Basically:

```
dpkg -i mpt3sas-15.00.00.00-1_Ubuntu16.04.amd64.deb
```

It returns the following output:

```
(Reading database ... 113018 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mpt3sas-15.00.00.00-1_Ubuntu16.04.amd64.deb ...
pre 15.00.00.00
Unpacking mpt3sas (15.00.00.00-1) over (15.00.00.00-1) ...
postun 15.00.00.00
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_gIqVq7/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_gIqVq7/lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Working files in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_gIqVq7, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_QotG2g and overlay in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_4s5aQ6
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_RiD83t/lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_RiD83t/lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Working files in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_RiD83t, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_YW2Fm1 and overlay in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_jhGqll
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_COZjvn/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_COZjvn/lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Working files in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_COZjvn, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_2W2S79 and overlay in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_pElhFg
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_Ue1zIN/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_Ue1zIN/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Working files in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_Ue1zIN, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_aOAOVR and overlay in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_nfk8px
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_TSAsP8/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_TSAsP8/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
Working files in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_TSAsP8, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_vOKAle and overlay in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_gBPCHy
Working files in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_hA6seh, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_Geezyb and overlay in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_VE0JlP
Working files in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_39yjJk, early initramfs in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-FW_SnLNwC and overlay in /var/tmp/mkinitramfs-OL_zt3DyR
Uninstall Done.
Setting up mpt3sas (15.00.00.00-1) ...
post 15.00.00.00
post Install Done.
```

Despite the warnings, it seems the package gets installed correctly. The command `dpkg -s mpt3sas` returns:

```
Package: mpt3sas
Status: install ok installed
Priority: extra
Section: alien
Installed-Size: 2518
Maintainer: root <root@ubuntu16x64>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 15.00.00.00-1
Description: LSI MPT Fusion drivers for SAS 3.0
 Drivers for (i686, x86_64 and updates) for the
 LSI Corporation MPT Fusion Architecture parts.
 .
 (Converted from a rpm package by alien version 8.95.)
```

After rebooting the system, the old driver is still there. I can see it from `dmesg`:

```
[    3.754208] mpt3sas version 12.100.00.00 loaded
[    3.766770] mpt3sas_cm0: 64 BIT PCI BUS DMA ADDRESSING SUPPORTED, total mem (98847588 kB)
[    3.836145] mpt3sas_cm0: MSI-X vectors supported: 96, no of cores: 16, max_msix_vectors: -1
[    3.836621] mpt3sas0-msix0: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 61
[    3.836621] mpt3sas0-msix1: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 62
[    3.836621] mpt3sas0-msix2: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 63
[    3.836622] mpt3sas0-msix3: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 64
[    3.836622] mpt3sas0-msix4: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 65
[    3.836622] mpt3sas0-msix5: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 66
[    3.836623] mpt3sas0-msix6: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 67
[    3.836623] mpt3sas0-msix7: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 68
[    3.836624] mpt3sas0-msix8: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 69
[    3.836624] mpt3sas0-msix9: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 70
[    3.836624] mpt3sas0-msix10: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 71
[    3.836625] mpt3sas0-msix11: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 74
[    3.836625] mpt3sas0-msix12: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 75
[    3.836625] mpt3sas0-msix13: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 76
[    3.836626] mpt3sas0-msix14: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 77
[    3.836626] mpt3sas0-msix15: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 78
[    3.836627] mpt3sas_cm0: iomem(0x00000000a4fb0000), mapped(0xffffc9000cf00000), size(65536)
[    3.836628] mpt3sas_cm0: ioport(0x0000000000003f00), size(256)
[    3.894108] mpt3sas_cm0: sending message unit reset !!
[    3.895620] mpt3sas_cm0: message unit reset: SUCCESS
[    3.948983] mpt3sas_cm0: Allocated physical memory: size(18690 kB)
[    3.948984] mpt3sas_cm0: Current Controller Queue Depth(10104),Max Controller Queue Depth(10240)
[    3.948984] mpt3sas_cm0: Scatter Gather Elements per IO(128)
[    3.994549] mpt3sas_cm0: LSISAS3008: FWVersion(14.00.00.00), ChipRevision(0x02), BiosVersion(16.00.00.00)
[    3.994549] mpt3sas_cm0: Protocol=(
[    3.995026] mpt3sas_cm0: sending port enable !!
[    3.996931] mpt3sas_cm0: host_add: handle(0x0001), sas_addr(0x500605b009cbcea0), phys(8)
[    4.010103] mpt3sas_cm0: port enable: SUCCESS
```

and from `modinfo mpt3sas`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
alias:          mpt2sas
version:        12.100.00.00
license:        GPL
description:    LSI MPT Fusion SAS 3.0 Device Driver
author:         Avago Technologies <MPT-FusionLinux.pdl@avagotech.com>
srcversion:     0105FF6DD1EDBDD8C2A5345
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000095sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000094sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000097sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000096sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d0000007Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d0000006Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000087sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000086sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000085sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000084sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000083sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000082sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000081sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000080sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000065sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000064sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000077sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000076sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000074sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000072sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000070sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        scsi_transport_sas,raid_class
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-66-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           logging_level: bits for enabling additional logging info (default=0)
parm:           max_sectors:max sectors, range 64 to 32767  default=32767 (ushort)
parm:           missing_delay: device missing delay , io missing delay (array of int)
parm:           max_lun: max lun, default=16895  (ullong)
parm:           hbas_to_enumerate: 0 - enumerates both SAS 2.0 & SAS 3.0 generation HBAs
          1 - enumerates only SAS 2.0 generation HBAs
          2 - enumerates only SAS 3.0 generation HBAs (default=0) (ushort)
parm:           diag_buffer_enable: post diag buffers (TRACE=1/SNAPSHOT=2/EXTENDED=4/default=0) (int)
parm:           disable_discovery: disable discovery  (int)
parm:           prot_mask: host protection capabilities mask, def=7  (int)
parm:           max_queue_depth: max controller queue depth  (int)
parm:           max_sgl_entries: max sg entries  (int)
parm:           msix_disable: disable msix routed interrupts (default=0) (int)
parm:           smp_affinity_enable:SMP affinity feature enable/disbale Default: enable(1) (int)
parm:           max_msix_vectors: max msix vectors (int)
parm:           mpt3sas_fwfault_debug: enable detection of firmware fault and halt firmware - (default=0)
```

I tried `update-initramfs -u` and then `reboot` with no success.

Before trying to compile the driver (Avago provides the sources and instructions on how to compile it) I would like to know if this is the right way to install/update a driver on Ubuntu 16.04.2 TLS Server.

### Update 1

After messing around with zombie initramfs images of kernels that I never installed, I managed to install the driver without warnings. I issued the following commands:

```
update-initramfs -v -d -k 4.4.0-21-generic
update-initramfs -v -d -k 4.4.0-22-generic
update-initramfs -v -d -k 4.4.0-24-generic
update-initramfs -v -d -k 4.4.0-28-generic
update-initramfs -v -d -k 4.4.0-31-generic


for i in `find / -name "4.4.0-2*"` ; do rm -R $i ; done
for i in `find / -name "4.4.0-3*"` ; do rm -R $i ; done

update-initramfs -u
update-grub
```

`dpkg -i mpt3sas-15.00.00.00-1_Ubuntu16.04.amd64.deb` now returns:

```
Selecting previously unselected package mpt3sas.
(Reading database ... 97652 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mpt3sas-15.00.00.00-1_Ubuntu16.04.amd64.deb ...
pre 15.00.00.00
Unpacking mpt3sas (15.00.00.00-1) ...
Setting up mpt3sas (15.00.00.00-1) ...
post 15.00.00.00
post Install Done.
```

The problem is, after reboot the loaded driver is still the same. `lsmod | grep mpt3` returns:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
mpt3sas               221184  11
raid_class             16384  1 mpt3sas
scsi_transport_sas     40960  1 mpt3sas
```

### Update 2

I just found that the `mpt3sas-15.00.00.00-1_Ubuntu16.04.amd64.deb` package provided by LSI (the official driver package for Ubuntu 16.04) contains the driver compiled for certain kernel version.

`dpkg-deb -c mpt3sas-15.00.00.00-1_Ubuntu16.04.amd64.deb` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./usr/share/doc/mpt3sas/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       167 2016-11-16 13:17 ./usr/share/doc/mpt3sas/changelog.Debian.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       815 2016-11-16 13:17 ./usr/share/doc/mpt3sas/copyright
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/weak-updates/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/
-r--r--r-- root/root    508840 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/weak-updates/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/
-r--r--r-- root/root    509576 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-24-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/weak-updates/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/
-r--r--r-- root/root    508840 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/weak-updates/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/
-r--r--r-- root/root    509576 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/weak-updates/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/
-r--r--r-- root/root    509576 2016-11-16 13:17 ./lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/weak-updates/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
```

This means that the driver probably won't never be installed in my current kernel modules directory..

Comment: The install probably should have made the new driver active. If the LSI is not your bootable disk system, then you'll probably be OK to remove the old driver, and install the new driver... in `terminal` do `sudo rmmod mpt2sas` and `sudo modprobe mpt2sas`. Use `man rmmod` and `man modprobe` to see what these commands do. If that works for you, let me know, and I'll make a formal answer for you.

Comment: @heynnema LSI is my bootable disk system. Why should I remove `mpt2sas` if I'm trying to update `mpt3sas`?

Comment: Because the old driver is still loaded into your kernel. The new driver should be sitting on your hard disk waiting to get loaded. What I don't know is, since this is your bootable disk system, if you can directly do what I suggested without causing a problem. Somebody else may need to chime in on this. Hum... I just revisited your modinfo command, and it indicates the old driver. I wonder if your install didn't move the new driver into its place?

Comment: ps: you could try and reinstall the new .deb file by double-clicking on it, and letting gdebi (`sudo apt-get install gdebi`) install it again, and see if it drops the new driver into the right spot, and a reboot will pick it up?

Comment: I don't have a GUI a don't want do install one, if possible.. What should be the right place for the driver?

Comment: @heynnema I updated my answer with the output log of the installation process. Maybe it sheds some lights on this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to install the driver. First of all, LSI (Broadcom) provides the source files. I entered the source file directory and issued the following commands:

`./compile.sh` returns:

```
rm: cannot remove 'tags': No such file or directory
./compile.sh: line 50: ctags: command not found
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic'
  LD      /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas_base.o
  CC [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas_config.o
  CC [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas_warpdrive.o
  CC [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas_scsih.o
  CC [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas_transport.o
  CC [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas_ctl.o
  CC [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas_trigger_diag.o
  LD [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/pietro/N2215/Linux_Driver_RHEL6-7_SLES11-12_P14/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic'
```

`./load.sh` returns:

```
dev.scsi.logging_level = 0x1C0
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module mpt3sas.ko: File exists
```

So I tried to remove the current `mpt3sas` driver via `rmmod mpt3sas`, with no success:

```
rmmod: ERROR: Module mpt3sas is in use
```

I manually copied the just compiled kernel module into the proper directory:

```
cp /lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko /lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko.bk
cp mpt3sas.ko /lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt3sas/
```

I then run `update-initramfs -u`, rebooted and now `modinfo mpt3sas` returns:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/mpt3sas/mpt3sas.ko
alias:          mpt2sas
version:        15.00.00.00
license:        GPL
description:    LSI MPT Fusion SAS 3.0 Device Driver
author:         Avago Technologies <MPT-FusionLinux.pdl@avagotech.com>
srcversion:     B199EC43635A547B22D7056
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d000000C9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000095sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000094sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000097sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000096sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d0000007Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d0000006Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000087sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000086sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000085sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000084sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000083sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000082sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000081sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000080sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000065sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000064sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000077sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000076sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000074sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000072sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001000d00000070sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        scsi_transport_sas,raid_class
vermagic:       4.4.0-66-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           logging_level: bits for enabling additional logging info (default=0)
parm:           sdev_queue_depth: globally setting SAS device queue depth 
parm:           max_sectors:max sectors, range 64 to 32767  default=32767 (ushort)
parm:           command_retry_count: Device discovery TUR command retry count: (default=144) (int)
parm:           missing_delay: device missing delay , io missing delay (array of int)
parm:           host_lock_mode:Enable SCSI host lock if set to 1(default=0) (int)
parm:           max_lun: max lun, default=16895  (int)
parm:           hbas_to_enumerate: 0 - enumerates both SAS 2.0 & SAS 3.0 generation HBAs
                  1 - enumerates only SAS 2.0 generation HBAs
                  2 - enumerates only SAS 3.0 generation HBAs (default=-1,       Enumerated both SAS 2.0 & SAS 3.0 else SAS 3.0 only) (int)
parm:           mpt3sas_multipath: enabling mulipath support for target resets (default=0) (int)
parm:           disable_eedp: disable EEDP support: (default=0) (uint)
parm:           diag_buffer_enable: post diag buffers (TRACE=1/SNAPSHOT=2/EXTENDED=4/default=0) (int)
parm:           disable_discovery: disable discovery  (int)
parm:           allow_drive_spindown: allow host driver to issue START STOP UNIT(STOP) command to spindown the drive before shut down or driver unload, default=1, 
        Dont spindown any SATA drives =0 /  Spindown SSD but not HDD = 1/   Spindown HDD but not SSD =2/  Spindown all SATA drives =3 (uint)
parm:           prot_mask: host protection capabilities mask, def=0x07  (int)
parm:           protection_guard_mask: host protection algorithm mask, def=3  (int)
parm:           issue_scsi_cmd_to_bringup_drive: allow host driver to issue SCSI commands to bring the drive to READY state, default=1  (int)
parm:           sata_smart_polling: poll for smart errors on SATA drives: (default=0) (uint)
parm:           max_queue_depth: max controller queue depth  (int)
parm:           max_sgl_entries: max sg entries  (int)
parm:           msix_disable: disable msix routed interrupts (default=0) (int)
parm:           smp_affinity_enable:SMP affinity feature enable/disbale Default: enable(1) (int)
parm:           max_msix_vectors: max msix vectors (int)
parm:           mpt3sas_fwfault_debug: enable detection of firmware fault and halt firmware - (default=0)
```

Also, `dmesg | grep mpt3sas` returns:

```
[    3.654905] mpt3sas: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.707454] mpt3sas version 15.00.00.00 loaded
[    3.812218] mpt3sas_cm0: 64 BIT PCI BUS DMA ADDRESSING SUPPORTED, total mem (98847588 kB)
[    4.133670] mpt3sas_cm0: IOC Number : 0
[    4.134366] mpt3sas0-msix0: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 81
[    4.134366] mpt3sas0-msix1: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 82
[    4.134366] mpt3sas0-msix2: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 83
[    4.134367] mpt3sas0-msix3: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 84
[    4.134367] mpt3sas0-msix4: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 85
[    4.134367] mpt3sas0-msix5: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 86
[    4.134368] mpt3sas0-msix6: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 87
[    4.134368] mpt3sas0-msix7: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 88
[    4.134368] mpt3sas0-msix8: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 89
[    4.134369] mpt3sas0-msix9: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 90
[    4.134369] mpt3sas0-msix10: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 91
[    4.134369] mpt3sas0-msix11: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 92
[    4.134370] mpt3sas0-msix12: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 93
[    4.134370] mpt3sas0-msix13: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 94
[    4.134370] mpt3sas0-msix14: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 95
[    4.134371] mpt3sas0-msix15: PCI-MSI-X enabled: IRQ 96
[    4.134372] mpt3sas_cm0: iomem(0x00000000a4fb0000), mapped(0xffffc9000cfe0000), size(65536)
[    4.134372] mpt3sas_cm0: ioport(0x0000000000003f00), size(256)
[    4.441696] mpt3sas_cm0: IOC Number : 0
[    4.441698] mpt3sas_cm0: sending message unit reset !!
[    4.449668] mpt3sas_cm0: message unit reset: SUCCESS
[    4.622550] mpt3sas_cm0: Allocated physical memory: size(18690 kB)
[    4.628086] mpt3sas_cm0: Current Controller Queue Depth(10104), Max Controller Queue Depth(10240)
[    4.633588] mpt3sas_cm0: Scatter Gather Elements per IO(128)
[    4.870241] mpt3sas_cm0: LSISAS3008: FWVersion(14.00.00.00), ChipRevision(0x02), BiosVersion(16.00.00.00)
[    4.875699] mpt3sas_cm0: Protocol=(Initiator,Target), Capabilities=(TLR,EEDP,Snapshot Buffer,Diag Trace Buffer,Task Set Full,NCQ)
[    4.887009] mpt3sas_cm0: : host protection capabilities enabled  DIF1 DIF2 DIF3
[    4.899062] mpt3sas_cm0: sending port enable !!
[    4.906595] mpt3sas_cm0: host_add: handle(0x0001), sas_addr(0x500605b009cbcea0), phys(8)
[    4.917659] mpt3sas_cm0: port enable: SUCCESS
```

Now the only things I'm worried about is `mpt3sas: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`, but I imagine it's not an issue.

Comment: Wow, quite a torturous way to have to do it, but you have the right idea. You found that the .deb file only installed for a particular kernel. You compiled from source. However, the source didn't install the driver for you, you had to manually copy it yourself. You'll have to do this for EVERY kernel upgrade. Sigh. The "required key missing" is because Ubuntu won't load unsigned kernel modules. As such, it's not loaded right now (server might be different in this respect). You either need to sign the module (kind of a pain), or just turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS (easy).

Comment: There are other commands other than the ones I used in order to check if the driver is loaded? I think it's loaded based on `dmesg` and `modinfo` outputs. And yes, I'll have to compile the driver for every kernel update... :(

Comment: So, did you turn off `secure boot`? Also, if you install/learn dkms, you can write a short dkms.conf file, and dkms will compile/install the driver for you at every kernel upgrade. You'll probably still need to figure out why your compile/install didn't install the driver for you. You'll have to take apart the makefile, or load.sh, to see what it's trying to do. Also, check the ownership/permissions on the driver that you copied, in its final directory, as it may not be correct with your manual cp.